# Phpunit show uncovered lines of code via console

Tags: php, phpunit, travis-ci, clover

I am using clover to compute my code-coverage with PHPUnit and I am looking for a way to display the uncovered lines of code via console (could be a command, bash script or PHP script).

I have the HTML report, but, I can't open it as the tests run on Travis.

So, how can I display the uncovered lines of code in the `after_faillure` event of Travis ?

M.

Comment: The script from this [article](https://ocramius.github.io/blog/automated-code-coverage-check-for-github-pull-requests-with-travis/) could be a good start for a script fitting your needs.

Another option to get coverage information to the console is `phpunit --coverage-text` that will print statistics to the console.